# how to add active class on anchor tag when clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

This is the javascript code in which I am getting anchor tags in loop.
I want to add an active class on that anchor tag which is clicked or which is current page

```
function changePage(page)
{
  current_page = page;
  var page_span = document.getElementById("page");
  var number_of_pages = Math.ceil(videoData.length / records_per_page);
  var PageNum = "";
  for (var i = 1; i <= number_of_pages; i++) {
  PageNum += '<a class="page_link" href="javascript:changePage(' + i +')">'+ i +'</a> ';  //Page nos.
  }
 page_span.innerHTML =  PageNum;
}
```

HTML

```
Page: <span id='page'></span></div>
```

Comment: In your code, you're not using jQuery (nor you say you want to use it), so there's no need to tag it.

Answer (score 1):

```
function onClick(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    document.querySelector('.active-class-name').classList.remove('active-class-name')
    e.target.classList.add('active-class-name')
}

<a onclick="onClick">Hi</a>
```

think this will work for you